# What's "graphics software stack"?

Tags: graphics, 3d

Should be a pretty low level conception, would someone explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Graphics software stack" is not a familiar term as such, but it seems reasonable in light of software stacks in general.

A [software stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) is a set of software packages that work together to get something done; typically they are layered one on top of another, i.e. dependencies between the components are usually one-way, although not necessarily (see [LAMP stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)).

An example of a graphics software stack might include a scene graph framework like Google's O3D, which is written in Javascript; the scene graph framework uses a low-level library like WebGL (implemented as part of a browser); and the latter in turn can use shaders written in GLSL (which run on a graphics card).